# javascript - giving .onClick to each cell in a table

Tags: javascript, onclick, dynamically-generated

I have a problem - I want to add an .onClick event to each cell of a dynamically generated table while I am creating it.

```
cell.onclick = function(){                
        mouseClick(row_number,i, cell);                               
    };
```

However, it appears that the event is just added to the last cell in each row. How is it possible? Is it somehow overriding the previous ones? And how to make it work?

```
function drawRow(rowData, length, keys, row_number){   
 //rowData - object where the row data is stored, length-row length, keys - object with table keys stored, row_number - number of the row
    var rowData=rowData;
    var row = document.createElement("tr");    
    for(i=0; i<length; i++){    
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        console.log("Creating event for "+i+" .");
        cell.onclick = function(){                
            mouseClick(row_number,i, cell);                               
        };
        var key = keys[i];       
        var cell_text = document.createTextNode(rowData[key]);        
        cell.appendChild(cell_text);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }  
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the horribly inconvenient world of closures ;)

Comment: `i` has a global scope (as far as I can tell — this is bad practice, by the way) and `row_number` and `cell` are scoped to outer functions, so they will be the same for all cells. You could [fix it with a closure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/4642212), but I would strongly recommend **event delegation** instead.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue
See answer there for one possible solution and an explanation of javascripts infamous loop-closure issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing one of the most common problems in JavaScript-land.

Your onclick functions are not called until *after* that for-loop is done. When the for-loop is done, the value of `i` is that of `length`. Only then do you try to read it. In other words, every single one of your callbacks say

```
function () {mouseClick(row_number, i, cell}
```

By the time you finally execute the callback, the value of `i` is its last value.

If you are using ES6, instead write

```
for (let i=0; i<length; i++)
```

The `let` **gives each invocation of the block its *own* variable `i`**. In your code you only have one `i` shared among all the cells. That is why all cells are appearing to do the same thing!

If you are still in the ES5 game, replace the inner portion of your code with

```
    cell.onclick = (function (j) {
        return function () {
            mouseClick(row_number, j, cell); 
        }                              
    })(i);
```

This gives to each of your callback functions a copy of `i` at each point of the loop. The first time through the loop, `i` has a value of 0, and the callback you get is

```
function () {mouseClick(row_number, 0, cell}
```

The second iteration of the loop produces

```
function () {mouseClick(row_number, 1, cell}
```

and so on!

Pretty cool...but the ES6 way with `let` does the same thing, a bit more nicely.

(Alternatively, there are ways to do this thing with the `forEach` method on arrays. These also ensure the loop iterations do not share the index variable.)

Comment: Nice answer Ray - mind adding an ES5 solution as well? ES6 isn't fully supported yet, and there's a good chance OP isn't using ES6